# Once a due date passes and the card is done, how do I keep the card and lose the red due date alert?

Tags: trello

I have a card with a due date of today. The task is complete, and we've moved it to our "Done" list.

How can I update the card so that the due date icon is not red implying that it is late while retaining the date for historical reference?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The Possible Duplicate is "how do I change a due date?" whereas this is "how do I mark something "done" while keeping it on my board?"

Comment: no way this is a dupe. the referenced dupe only answers how to change the date. I don't want to date gone, but to be marked as met instead of late.

Comment: I have flagged it as needing attention from the mods.

Comment: Isn't moving it to your "Done" list the signal that it's done?

Comment: @Humpton it's more about the red visual cue. Yes, it is done based on the list membership. I was hoping I was missing a feature. In a quick scan of the page, the red catches the eye and gives an incorrect initial impression of the state of the card.

Comment: Personally I like the idea of dragging to done actually resulting in a removal of any due date, as while a due date remains it still displays these cards when a filter is applied; which doesn't make a good deal of sense when you're looking at time sensitive tasks. That said, the fact that the tasks are in the done stack is probably signal enough that the task doesn't require your attention!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [improved due dates feature](https://trello.com/card/board/due-dates-v2/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4db03961c9fd63357d0531b7) has been implemented.

To clear a due date, click on the card, then click the due date, then click the "Remove" button.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for Trello. It's a great app, and I'm sure it's only going to get better.

Comment: The owner asked to do this "while retaining the date for historical reference", which I'd also be interested in. Is there any way you think? It would be useful in a number of situations where after finishing the project, you need to go back and look at the time intervals in which you completed the stages of your project.

Comment: Same here - and when a date is amended by another user as i've lost my original schedule now the client has amended their dates...

Comment: Thanks but shouldn't that be automated - when a card is moved to "Completed" or "Done" list?

Comment: if you can consider  these suggestions  --http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/82815/101616 , then it will be great

Comment: FYI, the link to the due dates feature is broken.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a card with a due date, add a checklist to the card. Even a checklist of one item will do the trick.

When you have completed the checklist item(s), check them off. Once all the checklist items are checked off, the due date icon will turn from red to green, indicating that you have met your deadline.

You can, of course, do this in conjunction with moving the card into a “done” column.

Comment: I'm not experiencing the behavior you mentioned above. Checking off all items on my list turns my checklist green, but has not effect on the DUE Date color. Trello thinks the card is OVERDUE, but it's in my completed list and was moved there before the Due Date.

Comment: This would be great, but it isn't how the app behaves.

Answer (score 6):

Our team decided to remove members from the card once it goes into the "Done" list. That way it does not appear in anyone's card list, but unlike archiving, it remains in the Done list for future viewing.

Answer (score 4):

As of the [Nov 29, 2016 update](http://blog.trello.com/mark-a-trello-card-as-done), you can now check the due date as done when editing the card back.  This will cause the due date to show in green on both the card front and back.

Also, if you're using the calendar power up, the card title will be displayed using strike-through text on the calendar.

[image: Due date complete]

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be a great addition if the card itself had a "completed" check box similar to the check list items. At the moment, my workaround is to create a check list per card and add at least one item. It would be much quicker to simply set the card itself to "completed". Furthermore, it would be nice to add an optional "completion date" to a card or check list, which would be displayed if it differs from the original due date.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround: change the year to '99' or '2099' but leave the month and day the same, the button will be gray.

Comment: While this does change the visual cue and may be a reasonable short term work around. I can't accept putting bad data (invalid due date) as an ultimate solution to the problem. Luckily, the new due data is progressing in the queue at Trello. https://trello.com/card/board/due-dates-v2/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4db03961c9fd63357d0531b7

Comment: The link to the queue at Trello is now dead. What is the status of this? As far as I can see, we're still stuck with red due dates.

Answer (score 0):

As above, add a checklist to the card, with one item: 'Done'. (Or make this the last item on an existing checklist). When this is ticked it will appear as a green ticked box on the card. The red 'Date' box will fade over a period of days, making it distinct, to some extent, from other 'live' cards.

Comment: Please note that "above" really has no meaning within answers, since they can be sorted in numerous ways. It's better to link directly to the answer you're referencing.