# How can one suppress the "overdue" flag but keep a card visible in a list?

Tags: trello

There is an archived card in the development board with many questions about marking a card as "done" and overiding the red "overdue" flag on the due date.  No answers that I can see.  https://trello.com/c/dylnY7I7

There is another question/answer in the FAQ that doesn't address this point but is closely related  [How can I mark a card in Trello as done and keep it in the original list?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19787/how-can-i-mark-a-card-in-trello-as-done-and-keep-it-in-the-original-list)

The last answer on this question/answer sounded promising, but see below.  [Once a due date passes and the card is done, how do I keep the card and lose the red due date alert?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/once-a-due-date-passes-and-the-card-is-done-how-do-i-keep-the-card-and-lose-the)

I tried adding a single item in a checklist (item was named "done"). When I checked it off, I get a green tag saying "1/1" because the checklist is done, but the red due date tag is still there...

What I really want is:

1. Creating a due date should create a "done" box directly accessible on the card, in lists view.
2. Second best would be if you were required to check the box in the detailed card view
3. Impact of checking that box would be to suppress the "overdue" notification on any due date older than "now".
4. One could imagine a bunch of other nice impacts, also, but they start to get into the realm of embedded business rules, and make the product more complex.

But, "done" is such a fundamental concept to the idea of work, and there have been two years of complaints about the absence.

I like Trello, but I can see I'm going to hate looking at "overdue" flags for tasks I've completed.

Does anyone have a workaround not mentioned above?

Is there a link to an explanation from Trello folks that would make it clear to me that I'm looking at the "doneness" of work in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

To work around this, I append the completed date to the card title (due date) and remove the calendar date just before archiving the card. (or moving it to Completed / Done list)

Alternatively, I put the date in an activity entry instead.

Card Title (Jan 4)

OR

Activity:
Card completed on Jan 4